# How to create a continuum animation in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: silverlight, animation, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I know there is a continuum transition in windows phone 7 and it doesn't seem to be included in the silverlight toolkit yet.

Any ideas how to create one?

Thanks in adv. :)

**UPDATE**

At last I took some code from Kevin Marshall's [excellent post](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2010/10/13/wp7-page-transitions-sample/) regarding wp7 page transitions and I think this post will give you a good start. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure which animation you're referring to as continuum however if it's the one I think you're talking about then [Metro in Motion Part #3 - Flying Titles](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/04/metro-in-motion-3-flying-titles/) may be some help. If not there are a few other articles in the series that could help you build your own.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone using the Silverlight Toolkit, I've created a Continuum Transition class that you can drop straight into your project and start using like the other transitions in the toolkit.

Check out the details here: [Continuum Transition for Windows Phone Silverlight Toolkit | Benjii.Me](http://benjii.me/2011/11/continuum-transition-for-windows-phone-silverlight-toolkit/)

Comment: +1, good work! I will definitely check it out when I have time. :)