# ANIMATING Page Transition in WP7 in C#

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Can anyone tell me how to animate a page transition in windows phone 7 by using C#. I have seen some samples which explain this in xaml. But I need to do it in C#.

Comment: I asked a similar question a couple of days ago, here is the link. :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615831/how-to-create-a-continuum-animation-in-windows-phone-7

Comment: What is it about the page transitions that means you need to do it in code instead of in the XAML?

Comment: @Derek Lakin: yes, i want to do it in C# code

Comment: I got that, I just don't understand why. Why make your life harder than it needs to be?

Answer (score 1):

you can follow this awesome tutorial: http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-7-Navigation-Transitions-Step-By-Step-guide

Comment: This actually helped me a lot, I have been searching for a proper way to get this done and all leads came up pretty short.