# Making ListBoxItem Selected Animation finish before Navigating

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, storyboard

I have a `ListBoxItem` style which I'm creating to mimic the 'Down and Away' style which happens when you click on a app in the marketplace app.

If I don't handle the `SelectionChanged` event, it works OK(doesn't match perfect, but hey :p), however when I handle `SelectionChanged`, the page just instantly navigates before the animation completes.

Ideally, I'd be interested in learning how to handle letting an animation complete before navigating to a generic page. I understand I could probably use a `DispatcherTimer` to wait, but I'd prefer to do something like:

```
if (selected item has storyboard, and storyboard is going)
   when finished, navigate to page2.


<Style x:Key="StretchedListBoxStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">

        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                         To=".5" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="1" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="900" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="30" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer"
                                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                        HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform />
                            </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                            <ContentControl.Projection>
                                <PlaneProjection />
                            </ContentControl.Projection>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about the continuum animation, which is not included in the toolkit. This animation shouldn't happen inside the `ListBoxItem` style.

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615831/how-to-create-a-continuum-animation-in-windows-phone-7) a while ago and I believe either one can give you what you want to achieve. :)